External filtering does not filter rows of TreeGrid data
I would like to use External Filtering with TreeGrid data, but I cannot get the rows to filter.
I've created a modified version of the example for External Filtering from the AGGrid site: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/external-filter-forked-4lhymj
If you set treeData to false, the filters work. If you set it to true, the rows are not filtered I the grid view, but the built-in filters are updated, suggesting that at least part of the grid "knows" the data changed. I set the Age column filter type to agSetColumnFilter and when you choose the different external filters, you can see the values in the Age column set filter change.
